# How to add attribute to Nokogiri node?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm trying to add an attribute to an existing Nokogiri node. What I've done is this:

```
node.attributes['foobar'] = Nokogiri::XML::Attr.new('foo', 'bar')
```

But I get the error:

```
TypeError Exception: wrong argument type String (expected Data)
```

What is a `Data` data type, and how do I add an attribute to the Nokogiri object?

Thanks!

Answer (score 56, accepted):

I believe you should just need to use [the []= method](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-[]%3D), i.e.

```
node['foo'] = 'bar'
```

You could also use `node.set_attribute('foo', 'bar')`.

Comment: This is what the Nokogiri docs say to do. Are you sure your `node` object is actually a `Nokogiri::XML::Element`? What was the error you got when you did `node['foo'] = 'bar'`?

Comment: actually, you're right - that was a mistake on my part.
greg - do you mind hitting edit and submit on your question so i can upvote it? thanks!

Comment: Done.  I also linked to the RDoc for the method in question on Nokogiri::XML::Node.

Comment: another thing if you're wondering why this didn't work is to make sure that you're writing out the modified object. =)