# nokogiri in ruby, create new value inside XML

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri, nodes

This is my XML:

```
<Instance ID="1" Type="CrossProtocol.CrossProtocolHost" NoDelay="False" KeepAlive="False" LocalIP="0.0.0.0" LocalPort="443" ServiceID="-1" MaxConnections="0" RemoteIP="127.0.0.1" RemotePort="443" CallBackPort="444" Description="HttpProxy" DesignatedIP="1.1.1.1" ProtocolName="SftpProxy" >
    <IPAddressRestriction Name="Restrict or grant access to services based on IP addresses" Type="0" Description="">
    </IPAddressRestriction>
  </Instance>
```

I want to add the field (node?) `CertificateSubject="/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=bla.com"` after the `"ProtocolName="SftpProxy""`, only when the RemotePort is 443 and the CallBackPort is 444

I tried using this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse(File.open("/opt/file/Config.xml"))
doc.xpath('//Instance/[@RemotePort = 443 and @CallBackPort = 444]').each do |node|
  CertPath = Nokogiri::XML::Node.new "CertificateSubject", doc
  CertPath.content = "/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=bla.com"
  node.add_next_sibling(CertPath)
end
```

But got errors, whats the right way to do that ?

EDIT

The expected XML should look like this:

```
<Instance ID="1" Type="CrossProtocol.CrossProtocolHost" NoDelay="False" KeepAlive="False" LocalIP="0.0.0.0" LocalPort="443" ServiceID="-1" MaxConnections="0" RemoteIP="127.0.0.1" RemotePort="443" CallBackPort="444" Description="HttpProxy" DesignatedIP="1.1.1.1" ProtocolName="SftpProxy" CertificateSubject="/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=bla.com">
    <IPAddressRestriction Name="Restrict or grant access to services based on IP addresses" Type="0" Description="">
    </IPAddressRestriction>
  </Instance>
```

Comment: You want to add node or attribute ?

Comment: Just show the what expected xml should look like ?

Comment: Edited, Can you look again ?
I believe I want to add a new Attribute with a value.

Comment: @Ba7a7chy the problem is you're adding a node when you want to be adding an attribute, I'll write you an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are basically want to add [*attribute*](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Attr.html), not a [`Node`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html).

```
require 'nokogiri'

xml = <<-XML
<Instance ID="1" Type="CrossProtocol.CrossProtocolHost" NoDelay="False" KeepAlive="False" LocalIP="0.0.0.0" LocalPort="443" ServiceID="-1" MaxConnections="0" RemoteIP="127.0.0.1" RemotePort="443" CallBackPort="444" Description="HttpProxy" DesignatedIP="1.1.1.1" ProtocolName="SftpProxy" >
    <IPAddressRestriction Name="Restrict or grant access to services based on IP addresses" Type="0" Description="">
    </IPAddressRestriction>
  </Instance>
XML

doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.xpath('//Instance[@RemotePort = 443 and @CallBackPort = 444]').each do |node|
  node['CertificateSubject'] =  "/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=bla.com"
end

puts doc
# >> <?xml version="1.0"?>
# >> <Instance ID="1" Type="CrossProtocol.CrossProtocolHost" NoDelay="False" KeepAlive="False" LocalIP="0.0.0.0" LocalPort="443" ServiceID="-1" MaxConnections="0" RemoteIP="127.0.0.1" RemotePort="443" CallBackPort="444" Description="HttpProxy" DesignatedIP="1.1.1.1" ProtocolName="SftpProxy" CertificateSubject="/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=bla.com">
# >>     <IPAddressRestriction Name="Restrict or grant access to services based on IP addresses" Type="0" Description="">
# >>     </IPAddressRestriction>
# >>   </Instance>
```

`Nokogiri::XML::Node` *attributes* can be accessed like *Hash key/value* pairs. Thus, there is a method [`[]=(name, value)`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Node.html#method-i-5B-5D-3D), which works as - *Set the attribute value for the attribute name to value*.

Inside the `#each` block, `node` is nothing but a `Nokogiri::XML::Node`, thus you can add the new *attribute/value* to this `node` using `[]=` method as I said above.

Comment: nice, beat me to it! :)

Comment: @MikeH-R No problem, if anything wrong you found like my another [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24207799/2767755), help me to improve. :-)

Comment: No, looks perfect, only improvement could be to mention that OP made a mistake in his xpath which you corrected.

Comment: @MikeH-R Your comment saved my life again. I forgot to mention it.

Comment: Although an [`Attr` _is_ a `Node`](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/attr.rb#L3), but [Nokogiri explicitly checks for and disallows it here](https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/blob/v1.6.2/lib/nokogiri/xml/node.rb#L952-L953). So much for [substitutability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle)!

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in the comment it's an attribute that you want to add, in addition you have an error in your xpath (you tried to descend a node with a forward slash when you shouldn't have). see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614458/how-to-add-attribute-to-nokogiri-node) for info on adding an attribute.

```
doc.xpath('//Instance[@RemotePort = 443 and @CallBackPort = 444]').each do |node|
  node['CertificateSubject'] = "/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=bla.com"  
end  

> doc.to_xml
#=> "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>\n<Instance ID=\"1\" Type=\"CrossProtocol.CrossProtocolHost\" NoDelay=\"False\" KeepAlive=\"False\" LocalIP=\"0.0.0.0\" LocalPort=\"443\" ServiceID=\"-1\" MaxConnections=\"0\" RemoteIP=\"127.0.0.1\" RemotePort=\"443\" CallBackPort=\"444\" Description=\"HttpProxy\" DesignatedIP=\"1.1.1.1\" ProtocolName=\"SftpProxy\" CertificateSubject=\"/OU=Domain Control Validated/CN=bla.com\">\n    <IPAddressRestriction Name=\"Restrict or grant access to services based on IP addresses\" Type=\"0\" Description=\"\">\n    </IPAddressRestriction>\n  </Instance>\n"
```