# Use functional programming to perform a transformation on each item in a hash

Tags: ruby

What is the most concise way to convert this:

```
{
    "AT"=>"de-DE",
    "DE"=>"de-DE",
    "LI"=>"de-DE"
}
```

to this?

```
{
    "AT"=>"de",
    "DE"=>"de",
    "LI"=>"de"
}
```

I can't see a way to do this with `Hash.map`.

I don't want to create any temporary variables or mutate the initial hash.

Comment: This is a Q&A website... What's wrong with 'fishing for answers' exactly?

Comment: Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic, especially #3 in the list, along with http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist. Stack Overflow is Q&A yes, but it's not for any question. There are some that are off-topic, and the FAQ explains that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Hash[h.map{|k,v| [k,v[0..1]]}]
```

Comment: Better - so you go from an array of arrays back to a hash, but isn't there a more direct way to do this?

Comment: Ok I'm accepting this one for now but crossing my fingers that there's some secret thing built into `Hash.map` or some other function or library that does this without going via a nested array.

Comment: There is no `Hash#map`. There is only `Enumerable#map`, and all `Enumerable` transformation methods always return `Array`s.

Comment: Michael, I'm perplexed why you selected this answer, as you said you didn't want temporary variables (here the array created by `map`), and there are other answers that comply with that requirement.

Answer (score 2):

```
h = {
    "AT"=>"de-DE",
    "DE"=>"de-DE",
    "LI"=>"de-DE"
}
p result = h.each_with_object({}){|(k,v), res| res[k] = v[0,2] }
# => {"AT"=>"de", "DE"=>"de", "LI"=>"de"}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do

```
hash = {
    "AT"=>"de-DE",
    "DE"=>"de-DE",
    "LI"=>"de-DE"
}

Hash[hash.map { |k,v| [k,v[/(.*?)-/,1]] }]
# => {"AT"=>"de", "DE"=>"de", "LI"=>"de"}
```

Another way :-

```
hash.each_with_object({}) { |(k, v), h| h[k] = v[/(.*?)-/,1] }
# => {"AT"=>"de", "DE"=>"de", "LI"=>"de"}
```

Comment: I've clarified my question to show that I want to avoid a temporary variable or mutating my original hash. I want to just create a new hash with modified values inline.

Comment: @MichaelForrest Nothing I destroyed.. Previous one reverted.. :-)

Comment: Tiny point, I'd use `/(.*?)-/` just in case there are other cases where there is more than one dash (lazy is genarally preferable). Obviously doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: @MikeH-R Thanks,.. I am not good in *regex*, but sometime try to use it.. so it happened :-)

Comment: Not so interested in the string conversion - more the mapping stuff. (I'm doing v.split('-').first)

Comment: I find the `hash.each_with_object` approach particularly difficult to read! ;)

Comment: @MichaelForrest If you want to avoid the *intermediate array*, then `#each_with_object` is better go AFAIK :-)

Comment: The crux of this question is that I want it to read *forward* like `[1,2,3].map{|n| n + 1}` does. These mechanisms mean I have to jump backwards and forwards through the line when reading it which feels overly complicated. `each_with_object` employs a `memo` thing and I always end up having to refer to documentation when such things are involved. And it's not much different to initializing an empty hash on the previous line. I just wish there was a `Hash.transform_values` method or something like that to let me go `{'a','b'}.transform_values{|v| v.uppercase}` or whatever.

Comment: @MichaelForrest You can raise a *feature request*, but currently no Ruby don't have. You have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Given a recent enough version of Ruby, this does the trick and "reads forward" like you wanted:

```
h.map { |k,v| [k, v[0..1]] }.to_h
#=> {"AT"=>"de", "DE"=>"de", "LI"=>"de"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will work

```
p = Hash.new
{"AT"=>"de-DE", "DE" => "de-DE", "LI" => "de-DE" }.each{ |k,v| p[k] = v.split('-')[0] }
```

Answer (score 0):

This does not create any intermediate object other than the hash and the strings that appear in the result.

```
{
    "AT"=>"de-DE",
    "DE"=>"de-DE",
    "LI"=>"de-DE"
}
.keys.each_with_object({}){|k, h| h[k] = "de"}
```

Comment: Regarding the creation of an intermediate object, don't you need `each_key` rather than `keys`?  If the string literal "de" is given, which seems a reasonable interpretation of the question, and intermediate objects were permitted, we could do `h.keys.product(["de"]).to_h`. (Yes, not the point of the question.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a disguised [Enumerable#each_with_object](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) that uses [Object#tap](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-tap) (Ruby v1.9+):

```
h = { "AT"=>"de-DE", "DE"=>"de-DE", "LI"=>"de-DE" }

{}.tap { |g| h.each_key { |k| g[k] = h[k][/[a-z]+/] } }
  #=> {"AT"=>"de", "DE"=>"de", "LI"=>"de"}
```